# get max zoom value from every device before setting my zoom ratio in camera controler

Tags: android, android-camerax

I want to get max zoom value from every device before. set my zoom ratio in camera controler, how do i do that?

```
 camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture, imageAnalyzer
            )
 val cameraControl = camera?.cameraControl
 cameraControl?.setZoomRatio(7F)
```

setting a specific no doesn't help as max zoom value differ for different camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it by calling `camera.cameraInfo.zoomState.value?.maxZoomRatio`.

See: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/CameraInfo#getZoomState()

Comment: it's a live data so ```cameraInfo.zoomState.value?.maxZoomRatio```. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone else who having the same issue.
I'm leaving my code below.

```
val camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                viewLifecycleOwner,
                cameraSelector,
                videoCapture,
                preview
            )
            val cameraControl = camera.cameraControl
            val cameraInfo =
                camera.cameraInfo 
            val maxZoomRatio =
                cameraInfo.zoomState.value?.maxZoomRatio// Set the default zoom level to the maximum zoom level supported by the camera
            zoomRatio = maxZoomRatio?.times(1F.div(2F))
            Log.d(TAG, "Max Zoom: $maxZoomRatio : $zoomRatio")
            if (zoomRatio != null) {
                cameraControl.setZoomRatio(zoomRatio!!)
            }
```